# How to escape special chars in an xml soap body for a soap request?

Tags: xml, soap, escaping

I am trying to consume a soap server. Values needs to be sent which may contain certain special chars, namely `'`, `&`, `$` `:`, and `*`, e.g.:

```
foo'bar&$bazz:*
```

I now that the value is correct, as I can consume the soap api indirectly through an external webfrontend that internally communicates with the soap server. I do not know what kind of transformation it applies to the payload nor do I have access to check.

I wonder: Is there a common way to escape / encode special chars for soap requests?

I tried using cdata:

```
<![CDATA[foo'bar&$bazz:*]]>
```

I tried using escape sequences:

```
& (ampersand): &#38;
' (apostrophe or single quote): &#39;
```

yet all to no avail.

I am trying to contact the provider of the soap service, yet in the meantime I wonder if there is a common escaping strategy that I can employ that should be default for soap servers to understand.

Comment: Both your approaches are perfectly correct. If something is failing, you need to tell us more precisely what you are doing and what the failure symptoms are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape strategy that worked for me was to not escape the `'` but only the `&`like this:

```
foo'bar&amp;$bazz:*
```